# What is the quickest way to unlock the Rose Knight?

Tags: lords-mobile

I know that in Lords Mobile to hire Rose Knight I need to unlock elite level 6-12 and collect tokens or medals for hiring the hero. Currently, I am in level 32. So, what is the quickest way to unlock the hero? Where I need to focus for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to unlock that hero is to rush your kingdom to level 17. Then build a team composition to counter that 6-12 elite boss. It's highly recommended that your team consists of 2 stunners, one tank, one damage dealer, and one healer. I also suggest that your heroes are at least level 50 before attempting the dungeon. Levels do matter! The team that I used had Prima Donna, Death Knight, Child of Light, Black Crow, and Tracker.

Answer (score 0):

You need heroes of level 50 
Deployment 
One stunner(Child of light).
Two damage dealers(Tracker and Black Crow).
Two healers(Primma Donna and Sea Squire).
In first round use skills or Primma Donna and Black Crow.
In second round use all the skills 
In third round stun rose knight before justice call and don't give any chance for shield throw.
Note-Sea Squire and Black Crow are compulsory.